# How to install Ubuntu on a laptop external HDD for use in another PC?

Tags: installation, external-hdd

I have several Intel Pentium II 333 based PCs which I want to install Ubuntu on. All PCs are identical, however they have no floppy nor do they have a CD drive. They all use 2½ HDD.

I intend on using my laptop to install Ubuntu onto the HDD in an external enclosure, then install the HDD in to the PCs and run Ubuntu.

The PCs will not boot from USB.

Comment: Some day I installed Ubuntu on an external drive. The problem was/is that boot information is saved on the same computer and that Ubuntu didn’t boot in any other computer. You may want to use Ubuntu in live mode on those PCs.

Comment: You seem to have a very old processor. I hope you have already seen the [System Requirements for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). Your only option is to install a Server Edition - the Processor is not powerful enough for a Desktop Edition.

Comment: @Robert What do you want to do with this post? Adapt it for newer PCs? You can edit it, close it or remove it. Also, you can create a new answer, telling us any new result.